# How do I Add Button In AJAX Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have one file PHP for show datatable

My index

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('cari').
    addEventListener('click', jalankan);

    function jalankan(){
        const unit = document.getElementById('unitcari').value;
        const nosam = document.getElementById('nosam').value;
        const tahun = document.getElementById('tahun').value;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'get/rek_cari.php',
            data: {'unitcari': unit, 'nosam': nosam, 'tahun': tahun},
            cache: false,
            success: function(show){
                $('#tampilkan').html(show);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And this is my code show datatable

```
<?php  
require '../../konfigurasi.php';


$unit = $_REQUEST['unitcari'];
$nosam = trim($_REQUEST['nosam']);
$tahun = $_REQUEST['tahun'];

?>

<div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Alamat</th>
                <th>Bulan</th>
                <th>Tahun</th>
                <th>Awal</th>
                <th>Akhir</th>
                <th>Rupiah</th>
                <th>Aksi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <?php 
                $select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM datatran WHERE no_unit = '$unit' AND no_samb = '$nosam' AND tahun = '$tahun' ORDER BY bulan ASC");

                $a = 1;
                foreach ($select as $tr) :
            ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $a++ ?></td>
                <td><?= $tr['nama']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $tr['alamat']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $tr['bulan']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $tr['tahun']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $tr['awal']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $tr['akhir']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $tr['rupiah']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" id="hapus" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

</div>
```

I want to add button in my table but, I don't know what to do
because that table different files, I can make if that PHP, but I want to make not reload

Comment: where you want to add button? Button is there already

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you want to achieve, and what are you're currently achieving?

Comment: sorry.. I mean, I want the buttons work, i don't know how it works because it's in a different file,